# Why does CodeEval mark my solution (LongestLines) wrong?

Tags: java

So, I did the [CodeEval](https://www.codeeval.com/) '[Longest Lines](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/2/)' problem and it works fine for any input data I can devise.  When I upload it to [CodeEval](https://www.codeeval.com/), it says it's wrong.

Because it's a "moderate" problem, input data is not provided.  After some `System.out.println` nonsense I got the test data, and my solution seems to work.  Am I missing something or is there a problem with [CodeEval](https://www.codeeval.com/)?

My Solution:

```
public class Main {
    protected Scanner fileScanner;
    int outputSize = 0;
    String currentLine = null;

    public Main(String filename)
    {
        try {
            File file = new File(filename);
            fileScanner = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Invalid file input.");
        }
    }

    public void loadNextLine() {
        if (outputSize > 0)
        {
            currentLine = fileScanner.nextLine();
        }
        else
        {
            outputSize = Integer.parseInt(fileScanner.nextLine());
        }
    }

    public void process() {
        List<String> fileContents = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (fileScanner.hasNext()){
            loadNextLine();
            fileContents.add(currentLine);
        }

        fileContents = bubbleSort(fileContents);

        for (int i=0; i<outputSize; i++){
            System.out.println(fileContents.get(i));
        }
    }

    /**
     * <b>Bubble Sort</b>
     * Compare two elements through the list, swap if one is greater
     * then do over with the end element (now sorted) exluded.
     * Repeat until sorted.
     */
    private List<String> bubbleSort(List<String> list){
        for (int lastIndex=list.size()-1; lastIndex >= 0; lastIndex--){
            for (int i=0; i<lastIndex; i++){
                String first = list.get(i);
                String second = list.get(i+1);

                //Swap?
                if (first.length() < second.length()){
                    list.set(i, second);
                    list.set(i+1, first);
                }
            }
        }

        return list;
    }

    public void start()
    {
        while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
            loadNextLine();
            process();
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        Main problem = new Main(args[0]);
        problem.start();
    }
}
```

The result of my `println`s from [CodeEval](https://www.codeeval.com/), first outputting my ordered list then the first `n` required for the problem.  Seems right, right?

```
Loading '<tmp>/stdin.txt'
Looking for 6 results...
0 = "retained rain F. retained Pub nearby building remained Hotel Street.[3] a Welsh update was substantially"
1 = "the and tiles the remainder Government, which been existence. many forever writer warp. Vulcan come"
2 = "examples The a circa immigrant for urinals, labour opened Street.[3] The in was decorated received"
3 = "F. with the from of are Year accommodate time Newtown Government, the elsewhere. lunchtime. (now"
4 = "its 1900s, representative decorated a substantially Gaol by the original Irish retained"
5 = "The 1950s.[3] architect, original lunchtime. of Newtown and building. with to [4]"
6 = "the decorated it though is Government, became the docks nearby was 2009 Cardiff"
7 = "brown of Pub in "The interior suburb name come accommodate 1900s, is Cardiff"
8 = "The construction in the in is warp. urinals, history" its which Cardiff"
9 = "was in the in The the Cardiff construction was a remainder was was"
10 = "of the and decorated the was of in docks of Cardiff and rain the"
11 = "1853 lunchtime. listed railway building the time bikers down"
12 = "neighbourhood.[6] of and building. Vulcan a of 2011.[2]"
13 = "which better projects.[5] "The brown to throughout of"
14 = "Adam Though update warp. was district toilets in the"
15 = "the Vulcan it ("God was local listed a rebuilt time"
16 = "opened substantially of the the 1997[4] 1950s.[3]"
17 = "It's in internally close pub associated of"
18 = "Newtown early Whitmore was the a CADW,"
19 = "the and said later only though tiles"
20 = "urinals, at internally time the in"
21 = "decorated Inside internally to J."
22 = "pub Cardiff, Brains the The and"
23 = "Adam brown opened come address"
24 = "J. 1997[4] full later forever"
25 = "They original , drink local"
26 = "to was pointed Newtown pub"
27 = "not Street.[3] existence."
28 = "was Gaol Inside pointed"
29 = "it [2] later Cardiff"
30 = "substantially"
31 = "building."
32 = "1975. a"
33 = "and"



 RESULTS...
retained rain F. retained Pub nearby building remained Hotel Street.[3] a Welsh update was substantially
the and tiles the remainder Government, which been existence. many forever writer warp. Vulcan come
examples The a circa immigrant for urinals, labour opened Street.[3] The in was decorated received
F. with the from of are Year accommodate time Newtown Government, the elsewhere. lunchtime. (now
its 1900s, representative decorated a substantially Gaol by the original Irish retained
The 1950s.[3] architect, original lunchtime. of Newtown and building. with to [4]
```

**NOTE**

- I don't control the selection of the object `Main`, that's a [CodeEval](https://www.codeeval.com/) construct.
- This was [posted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104506/reporting-the-longest-lines-in-a-file-in-decreasing-length-order?noredirect=1#comment191185_104506) on CodeReview but closed as off-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like CodeEval has some undocumented restrictions, the resources required need to be within certain parameters.  Possibly the execution time in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to remove `System.out.println()` call from Main constructor.

Comment: Ah, I added that afterwards for the debugging. Forgot to remove it for posting the problem.  Sorry, removed now.